# Ruby replace elements in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
test_tweets = [
  "This president sucks!",
  "I hate this Blank House!",
  "I can't believe we're living with such a bad leadership. We were so foolish",
  "President Presidentname is a danger to society. I hate that he's so bad – it sucks."
  ]

banned_phrases = ["sucks", "bad", "hate", "foolish", "danger to society"]
```

Write me a program that filters out the following words from tweets: "sucks", "bad", "hate", "foolish", and "danger to society". Replace each negative word or phrase them with the word "CENSORED".

Not sure how to do this. Could someone shed some light?

```
new_array = test_tweets.join(" ").split(" ")
new_array.map { |word| word == banned_phrases.to_s ? "CENSORED" : word }.flatten!
```

Comment: new_array = test_tweets.join(" ").split(" ")
new_array.map {|word| word == banned_phrases.to_s? "CENSORED":word}.flatten!
This is what I could conjure up. :/
@SebastianPalma

Answer (score 1):

You're converting the whole banned_phrases array to a string, which would return something like

```
"[\"sucks\", \"bad\", \"hate\", \"foolish\", \"danger to society\"]"
```

So, there's no word in any tweet that can be equal to that (and probably wouldn't). The main problem seems to be in the comparison.

You could start iterating each tweet, split them, getting each word inside, and then check if the array with the banned phrases contains that specific word, if so, you return "CENSORED", otherwise the word. Then you can join with a whitespace each word in the generated array:

```
test_tweets = [
  "This president sucks!",
  "I hate this Blank House!",
  "I can't believe we're living with such a bad leadership. We were so foolish",
  "President Presidentname is a danger to society. I hate that he's so bad – it sucks."
]

banned_phrases = ["sucks", "bad", "hate", "foolish", "danger to society"]

censored_tweets = test_tweets.flat_map do |tweet|
  tweet.split.map { |word| banned_phrases.include?(word) ? 'CENSORED' : word }.join(' ')
end
p censored_tweets
# ["This president sucks!", "I CENSORED this Blank House!", "I can't believe we're living with such a CENSORED leadership. We were so CENSORED", "President Presidentname is a danger to society. I CENSORED that he's so CENSORED – it sucks."]
```

---

```
test_tweets.flat_map do |tweet|
  re = Regexp.union(banned_phrases)
  tweet.split.map { |word| word.gsub(re, 'CENSORED') }.join(' ')
end
# ["This president CENSORED!", "I CENSORED this Blank House!", "I can't believe we're living with such a CENSORED leadership. We were so CENSORED", "President Presidentname is a danger to society. I CENSORED that he's so CENSORED – it CENSORED."]
```

Comment: What about the first at last "sucks"? One is "sucks!" and the other "sucks!"

Comment: _Write a program that filters out the following words from tweets: "sucks", ..._ sucks isn't sucks!, I don't see that in the question. See the updated answer.

Comment: If it's wat you needed, you can accept the answer @kirtimansingh.

Answer (score 0):

Another one liner way,

```
test_tweets.map {|tweet| tweet.gsub!(Regexp.union(banned_phrases),'censored')}
```

it uses regular expression to match those banned phrases and globally replaces them

Comment: `Regexp.union` would be a better choice than using `Array#join`. Consider what happens when `banned_phrases = ['.', 'a|b']` or similar things.

Comment: @muistooshort edited, thanks for the suggestion, it does get messed up with `['.','a|b']` or other similar examples

Answer (score 0):

```
test_tweets = [
  "This president sucks!",
  "I hate this Blank House!",
  "I can't believe we're living under such bad leadership. We were so foolish",
  "President Presidentname is a danger to society. I hate that he's so bad -- it sucks."
  ]
banned_phrases = ["sucks", "bad", "hate", "foolish", "danger to society"]
censored_tweets = []

test_tweets.each do |tweet|
  censored_tweets << tweet.gsub(/(\w+)/) { |word|
    banned_phrases.include?(word.downcase) ? "CENSORED" : word
  }
end

puts censored_tweets
```